# Create a Report in vb6 via Data Grid

Tags: datagrid, vb6

Again, This is very simple, I know but hard for me. Now, what I have done is selected an Excel file and copied the data into Data Grid. Now My question is = "Is it really possible to create a report from this Data Grid?" or I am chasing some impossible.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: DataGrid controls are for entry and editing of data.  For reporting you'd probably want to query the database that you were updating.  The query results can be used in a DataReport, a 3rd party reporting tool, or a custom report "drawn on" the Printer object using a lot of code.

Comment: Should I use Crystal Report!

Comment: You can use lots of things.  All of them have a learning curve though, and some tools work better for some kinds of reporting but not so well for others. I'd start by trying the DataReport feature in VB6 and move on to something else if that isn't flexible enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to Prepare Data Report from Data Grid in vb6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873228/how-to-prepare-data-report-from-data-grid-in-vb6)